# bind toggleClass to ajax:success callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a link that will toggle a boolean field in my database, and, based on a conditional helper method, toggle the link text on ajax:success.

The field value is updated fine.

I'm also trying to toggle the link class at the same time, however this seems to work only on each second click.

```
$("#approval_link_<%= @review.id %>")
  .bind("ajax:success", function() {
    $(this).text("<%= approve_link_text(@review) %>").toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

How would you go about achieving this? Am I missing the obvious? Thanks!